# How to turn off remote debugging to open this site in IE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge, remote-debugging

I am automating an application in Microsoft Edge browser on Windows 11 system. How can I remove that from running browser instance. I also checked similar question asked on stackoverflow but didnt get much help to overcome this banner.

[Turn off remote debugging to open this site in internet explorer mode. Otherwise, it might not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335929/turn-off-remote-debugging-to-open-this-site-in-internet-explorer-mode-otherwise)

Environment Used :
Windows 11

Microsoft Edge : 105.0.1343.42

Selenium : 3.141.59

BaseDriver.Java

```
else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",
                        FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getDriverPath() + "/msedgedriver.exe");
                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
                // Creating an object of EdgeDriver
                driver = new EdgeDriver();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();

                // Deleting all the cookies
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

                // Specifiying pageLoadTimeout and Implicit wait
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ChromeTest.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ChromeTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
            <artifactId>winium-elements-desktop</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0-1</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
            <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
        

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>  

    <!--     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-4</version>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies> 



</project>
```

**Please refer attached screen shot for your reference**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think you have configured the site in IE mode site list and tried to automate it in IE mode. It's the expected behavior that you see the error message because you're not using the right way to automate IE mode in Edge.

The right way to automate IE mode in Edge is using IE Driver instead of Edge Driver. For the detailed steps, please follow this guide: [Use Internet Explorer Driver to automate IE mode in Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java).

Comment: IE doesn’t support windows 11.

Comment: You don't need to use IE 11 desktop application, just download the **IE driver** and follow the steps in the doc. It will launch IE mode in Edge.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\User\\ChromeTest\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
  ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
  ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("D:\\User_Workspace\\ChromeTest\\drivers\\msedgedriver.exe");

  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);

  driver.get("http://www.bing.com");

Comment: I referred given document but browser is not opening :)

Comment: There's a little mistake in your code. `ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");` Here in `InternetExplorerOptions` you should define with additional properties that point to the **Edge browser**, not Edge WebDriver.